# Instantiate and load a block programmatically in twig template

Tags: 8, blocks, plugins

I created a simple block that shows some text grabbed from an external source, and it renders as expected when I place it from the back-end (Structure->Block Layout).

But I want to be able to place it via code only inside a twig template from the theme directory. I thought I would use {{ drupal_block('id defined in Block.php') }} from the [Twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module but it never works unless the block is first placed from the back-end which assigns it a machine name then I can display it anywhere using that machine name in drupal_block() instead of the id I defined in its source code.

So how can I instantiate it programmatically first and then place it the the twig template I want?

During my search I came across Plugin Derivatives, I don't know if it is the solution I want, or how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are other ways to solve this problem, but here is how I would do it.

Create your block, then go to admin/structure/block and place your block under "Disabled" list. You can then implement hook_preprocess_node in your .theme.php file.

#### theme file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node()
 */

function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('block_id');
  if ($block) {
    $variables['my_custom_block'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
  }
}
```

#### In your template twig file:

```
{% if my_custom_block %}
 {{ my_custom_block }}
{% endif %}
```

You just have to make sure that your block_id correct.

Comment: I like the approach, though I never saw a 'disabled' section in Drupal 8.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... If I disable the block it disappears whether using drupal_block() or preprocess_node().
Your twig code is missing a % at the opening if block and there is an extra space at the closing block.